# HADOOP_CONF_DIR already set still getting error, HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Trying to run a simple app on a cluster using YARN. I have set both

```
export HADOOP_HOME = /usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

in spark-env.sh file still I'm getting this error.

Do I need to make changes is some other files as well?
Is there any documentation and where am I going wrong?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: its in the title "When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment"

Comment: can you share the screenshots?

Comment: I managed to fix it by writing these lines in the users .profile file. so do have to write it again and again before running the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by writing these lines in the users .profile file. so do have to write it again and again before running the command
else just do

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/conf
```

before running the spark-submit command.

Comment: Ideally, this is set in `spark-env.sh` already, which might not be being read by your Spark submit command